# Trouble building tree for possible chess piece movements

Tags: ruby, binary, binary-tree, chess

I'm building a chess game that takes a start coordinate and end coordinate and builds a tree using BFS. I have two methods to find possible moves.

The #find_possible_positions_from_origin method logs every single possible square that chess piece can end up (for example a rook can end up either, north up to 7 spaces, south up to 7 spaces, left up to 7 spaces, and right up to 7 spaces. If the end coordinate ends up BEING one of these coordinates from #find_possible_positions_from_origin, it then runs another method directly under it #find_possible_incremental_moves that traverses every single one of these spaces by only 1 space at a time - the reason being so that it can check if each space is empty, and not just hop over another piece. It creates a "cell" on each of these spaces so that it can log the path to destination. Each cell remembers the path to it from the starting coordinate.

I'm having trouble getting the second variable #find_possible_incremental_moves run smoothly under the #find_possible_positions_from_origin method. A "cell" is supposed to be created at the destination coordinate of the board, so that I can have the path to it, and check if the path is occupied by any other pieces. But when I call the destination coordinate, I get *nil*.

Someone corrected me on a previous question that I shouldn't post my entire production code which makes sense, so I included the single #build_tree that I'm having trouble with I hope that's enough.

Here is my code that have for this section.

```
def build_tree
        @start_coor = convert_input_to_coor(@start)
        @destination_coor = convert_input_to_coor(@destination)
        @selected_piece = @gameboard[@start_coor[0]][@start_coor[1]]
        starting_cell = Cell.new(@start_coor[0], @start_coor[1])
        queue = []
        queue.unshift(starting_cell)
        until queue.empty?
            current = queue.shift
            possible_positions = find_possible_positions_from_origin([current.x, current.y])
            next if possible_positions.nil?

             if possible_positions.include?(@destination_coor)
                @selected_piece.possible_positions = find_possible_incremental_moves(([current.x, current.y]))

                @selected_piece.possible_positions.each do |move|
                    next unless !@dummyboard.board[move[0]][move[1]].instance_of? Cell

                    linked_cell = Cell.new(move[0], move[1])
                    current.edges << linked_cell
                    linked_cell.path = current.path + linked_cell.path
                    @dummyboard.board[move[0]][move[1]] = linked_cell
                    queue.push(linked_cell)
                end
            end
        end
       starting_cell
    end
```